# resample dataframe on values rather than time / merge dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which I would like to merge. Both dataframes were obtained from measurements, and read in from stored CSV files. Below is the minimal code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('file_charge.csv') #battery charging file
print(df1.head())
soc       volt
0  0.000052  46.489062
1  0.000246  46.600472
2  0.000537  46.714063
3  0.000833  46.823437
4  0.001125  46.919929
print(len(df1))
3052

df2 = pd.read_csv('file_discharge.csv') #battery discharging file
print(df2.head())
        volt       soc
0  56.064844  0.999797
1  55.608464  0.999458
2  55.236909  0.999117
3  54.908865  0.998753
4  54.639002  0.998398
print(len(df2))
2962
```

With timeseries data, I have found that resampling and using the datetime-index to merge/join/concat on to be great. What I want to do is create an overall file that contains the following:
soc | volt_charge | volt_discharge | volt_average

The issue I see at the moment is that the dataframes are of different length, which I don't know how to easily address. (How) Is it possible to downsample (or even upsample) a dataframe with a numeric index?

So far, my attempts at combining/merging the dataframes have failed. Using `pd.merge` results in an empty resulting dataframe, whereas `pd.merge_ordered` gives a df that has only 2 columns (soc and volt), rather than the desired 3 (soc, volt_1, volt_2), from which the additional fourth (volt_avg = mean(volt_1,volt_2)) column can be made.

In graphical terms: it is possible to graph both df1 and df2 on the same x- and y-axes, yet I don't know how the "visual" average of df1 and df2 could be created.[image: Voltage versus state of charge, charge and discharge curves]

Comment: Do you want the resulting dataset to have only the datetime-indexes which are present in both the original datasets?

Comment: @Christian No, as the measurements were performed on different days. The datetime-indexes in this case are not meaningful, unless you can enlighten me how they could be?

Comment: Consider [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to create bin groups of *soc* and then merge on this grouping and then run needed averages.